# What is the difference between "Куда ты идёшь?" and "Куда ты собрался?"

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление, глаголы, разница, глаголы-движения

I recently learned that

> **Куда ты собрался?**

usually gets translated as

> **Where are you going?**

*[Or, at least it does on Reverso.](https://context.reverso.net/translation/russian-english/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0+%D1%82%D1%8B+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%3F)*

This raised at least a couple of questions for me.  The first is the title of this post — What is the difference between

> **Kуда ты идёшь?**

and

> **Куда ты собрался?**

The second thing that piqued my curiosity is the fact that "собрался" is past tense perfective.  If one makes the decision to use **собраться**, why not use a future tense form of it?  But, as you can see from the Google Ngram below, "Куда ты соберёшься?" doesn't even make the cut:

[image]

I am also curious about the frequency of past tense perfective verbs being translated as present tense verbs in English.  Does this happen with great frequency?  Are there certain types of verbs that tend to do this?  Is "**собираться**" one of them, and, if so, does this group of verbs have a category with a name?  And, finally, is there a particular name for when a verb is past tense in the original language, but present tense in the translated language?

If you want more context, this whole inquiry came about after a learning session in which one of my Russian tutors on iTalki is helping me understand the dialog in this short film:

**[Ночь](https://vimeo.com/265641739)**

The phrase in question is found just shortly after minute 1:20, and conjugated for a female obviously (собралась vs. собрался).

I didn't realize I had so many questions about this phrase until after the session ended, but that's okay because somebody else might be curious about this, too.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132962/discussion-on-question-by-lisa-beck-what-is-the-difference-between---).

Comment: «Куда ты собрался?» is short for «Куда ты собрался идти?»

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on context — particularly whether the question is posed while the person addressed is preparing to leave, or in the process of actually leaving.

1. While preparing to leave (e.g. ironing their clothes):

   - Kуда ты идёшь? - Appropriate;
   - Куда ты собрался? - Not appropriate because preparations to leave are not yet concluded;
   - Куда ты собираешься? (Where are you preparing to go?) - Appropriate, because the question is about an ongoing process;
2. After preparations are concluded, but before starting off (e.g. the person addressed has put on new clothes, but hasn't walked out the door):

   - Kуда ты идёшь? - Appropriate;
   - Куда ты собрался? - Appropriate. It *may* imply disapproval — particularly if there were no visible preparations.
3. When someone is in the process of leaving (e.g. on the street):

   - Kуда ты идёшь? - Appropriate;
   - Куда ты собрался? - Appropriate; The crux here is that someone's appearance and/or behavior is unusual and suggests some special occasion.

Comment: Note that in 1 "Куда ты собрался?" is not appropriate in a positive meaning, but completely correct in the "disapproval" case - "you *decided* (собрался) to party with the other girl and now ironing your clothes".

Answer (score 5):

Let me start with the basics. Собирать means 'to gather', 'to put lots of things in one place'. Собираться means 'to gather oneself (or one's things)', 'to pack (one's belongings)'. Соберись! could mean either 'pack yourself!' or 'pull yourself together!', 'focus!', 'get ready!'). Getting ready for something implies being about to do it, in your example, to go.

Собрался is in the past tense because you're finished getting ready and now you're about to go. The full phrase might have been:

- Куда ты собрался идти? (Where have you gotten yourself ready to go?)

But usually in this phrase идти is dropped as it's already implied by куда, leaving just:

- Куда ты собрался? Where are you off to?

Comment: Sergey, you don't disappoint. Great answer!

Comment: I think I've even seen just Куда ты? with no идти to speak of, right?

Comment: @CocoPop, That's right. Куда ты? or Ты куда? work as complete sentences as well.

Comment: Thank you! Happy New Year to you.

Comment: In fact, «Ты куда?» is so overused, it's usually met with an irritated retort: «На куды́кину го́ру!». To avoid the cliche, my wife sees me off with: «Ты куда, Одиссей, от жены, от детей?..» @CocoPop

Comment: @CocoPop RE: I think I've even seen just Куда ты? with no идти to speak of, right? | My Russian tutor did mention that and though I know how you feel about Reverso, it does have a lot of examples where Куда ты? is translated as "Where are you going?"

Comment: @CocoPop  **RE: Never would I imagine that Куда ты? meant "where are you?"** | No, you're not missing anything.  I just confused Где ты? with Куда ты?  I edited my previous comment accordingly.  Thanks for calling me on it.

Comment: I figured as much :) so I deleted my comment, too. I think we're all on the same page now.

Comment: Love your answer Sergey and it makes me wish I could award more than one green check mark, but when I really take a close look at my question and then at the answers, I think I kind of have to give it to Alexander.  Plus, he has fewer points than you and I like spreading the wealth when I can.  Спасибо большое for this and all of your other consistently good contributions to this forum.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that **собираться** can effectively be compared to English *(to be) about to*. That would explain why it doesn't work in the future, since we, similarly, wouldn't say *you'll be about to go* except in some esoteric context. So my interpretation of **Куда ты собрался?** would be "Where are/were you off to?", or with a touch of disapproval, "Where do you think *you're* going?"

Another interpretation of **собрался** is *was going to* when we talk about future intentions in a past scenario. That's why there's no future equivalent, because in the present, we would just use the future tense:

[*past intention*] I was going to call you when I had the time, but it never panned out.

[*present intention*] I'm going to call you when I have the time.

Comment: What could, in your oppinion, relevant translations of your two last examples be? [for the past intention] Я собрался вам (по)звонить, когда время будет, но не спланировалось or Я собирался вам (по)звонить, когда время было/будет, но не спланировалось. [fot the Present intention] Я собрался вам (по)звонить, когда есть/будет время or Я собираюсь вам (по)звонить, когда есть/будет время.

Comment: I'd say, Я собирался тебе (по)звонить, and Я позвоню тебе.

Comment: Thank you. I am also interested in the translation of subordinate clauses. I.e. [for the past intention] "...когда время было or будет"?

Comment: That I don't know. You'll know better than me what sounds good in Russian.

Comment: I thought I would have known. But native speakers downvoted my answer. It means I was wrong on some issues.

Comment: @Eugene that doesn't sound right *я **собрался** позвонить, когда **будет** время*. Don't really want to analyze why, but that sounds ungrammatical. Should be *я собирался позвонить, когда будет время*.

Comment: @il--ya Thanks. I thought It was all about the time shift: for future references "Я собрался позвонить, когда будет время завтра" and "Я собирался позвонить, когда было время вчера" for the past.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference in the use of perfective "собраться-собрался" and impf. "собираться-собираешься" consists in the nuances they express. It can be one of "packing up/putting something on, clothes etc" or "planning, intending to do smth". Irrespective of whether you see someone packing up their things/belongings or preparing/putting on/changing clothes or having already put them on, or you run into them in the doorway, you can use either "собрался" or "собираешься" in the meaning of "having planned/intending to do smth":

- (someone is packing up their belongings or putting on/changing clothes)

  -*"Куда собрался/собираешься/вознамерился/намереваешься?"* (to put it literally, it would mean: "What have you planned to go to do, that I see you packing up/getting dressed?")

  *-"Cобрался/собираюсь/вознамерился/намереваюсь: погулять/cходить за продуктами/съездить в Вегас/уйти от тебя/совершить ограбление/научиться танцевать самбу!* (I've planned/intend to...).
- (you meet someone in the doorway, who's already dressed)

  -*"Куда собрался/собираешься/вознамерился/намереваешься?"*

  -*"Cобрался/собираюсь/вознамерился/намереваюсь: погулять/cходить за продуктами/съездить в Вегас/уйти от тебя/совершить ограбление/научиться танцевать самбу!*

Comment: >"Where have you planned to go that I see you packing up/getting dressed?" It doesn't mean "where are you off to?" — that's exactly what "Where are you off to" means. Otherwise, we just ask "Where are you going?"

Comment: @CocoPop But it is not my initial pattern. If I'm not mistaken it used to be: "What have you planned to go to do that I see you packing up/getting dressed?" And the answer should be: "I'm going to take a walk/to leave you/to knock a bank over/to take a trip to Vegas". And it is not "Where are you going?", it may be closer to "Where are you off to?" In Russian, as far as I've been in the know, "Куда собрался/собираешься" has little to do with "Куда ты идешь?" as far as a destination point is concerned.

Comment: @CocoPop Are the expressions "Where are you off to?" and "What are you going/intending/planning to do" interchangeable?

Comment: They can be, depending on the context and what the other person is doing.

Comment: @CocoPop Isn't it expedient that the verb "to intend" be used in the Present Perfect? "I have (long) intended to go to study dancing Samba".

Comment: It sounds strange. I'd say "I've been meaning to take up samba dancing for a long time."

Comment: @CocoPop I highly asses your touch (in dealing) with my English.  Inasmuch as I take in "take up" as "occupy oneself with, engage in, go in for etc", could I say: "I've been meaning to go study dancing Samba" to set off the idea of getting into studying Samba?

Comment: Eugene, the problem is that we don't "study" dance, per se, we start learning it in practice, so it's more common to say "I've been meaning to **take up** or **learn** samba."

Comment: @CocoPop I see. Would you allow of adding "go": "I've been meaning to go learn samba."?

Comment: Absolutely! 

Comment: @CocoPop That's the key point for the implication of " куда собрался/собираешься/собираешься". Thank you a raft of lots! (I don't abide by idiomacy. It makes any language unrestrained and lavish in a good sense)(:

Comment: Eugene, ¿what does this mean: I don't abide by idiomacy. It makes any language unrestrained and lavish in a good sense.

Comment: @CocoPop Sorry if my sentence might have misled you. I mean that I am not inclined to rigidly follow/adhere to using idiomatic, firmly established phrases and expressions. Why not using words freely (ad lib), as bricks and grammar as concrete, so that a (any) language will become more diverse, rich, lavish, lush and, I'd also subjoin, succulent ((: Maybe something will take on and become idiomatic.

Comment: ...because, like me, nobody will understand you :(

Answer (score 0):

In English the verb "to be going to" has 2 separate meanings: 1. To move physically, usually by foot; 2. To prepare, have the intention to do something.